# Why I can't build jupyter lab after installing jupyterlab-lsp extension?

Tags: python, node.js, npm, jupyter-lab

Disclamer: this is my first stackoverflow question.

So, I have been using jupyterlab for some time now, and I want to get this nice extension called jupyterlab-lsp. So i followed these (ordered) steps:

1. Enabled Extension Manager in Jupyter lab
2. Tried to install @krassowski/jupyterlab-lsp through the Extension Manager, but it prompt that I needed nodejs 5+ and npm.
3. So I went and did "pip install nodejs", and also downloaded and installed nodejs (through this link: https://nodejs.org/en/download/). According to them, npm is also installed together with nodejs.
4. Reopened jupyter lab, and now I was able to install @krassowski/jupyterlab-lsp. After that I was prompted to rebuild jupyter lab.
5. I used the command `jupyter lab build` and got the following error log:

```
[LabBuildApp] Building in C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab
[LabBuildApp] Yarn configuration loaded.
[LabBuildApp] Node v12.18.1

[LabBuildApp] Building jupyterlab assets (build:prod:minimize)
[LabBuildApp] > node C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\staging\yarn.js install --non-interactive
[LabBuildApp] yarn install v1.15.2
[1/5] Validating package.json...
[2/5] Resolving packages...
[3/5] Fetching packages...
warning vscode-languageclient@5.2.1: The engine "vscode" appears to be invalid.
info fsevents@1.2.11: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@1.2.11" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
[4/5] Linking dependencies...
warning " > @krassowski/jupyterlab-lsp@1.0.0" has incorrect peer dependency "@jupyterlab/application@~2.0.0".
warning " > @krassowski/jupyterlab-lsp@1.0.0" has incorrect peer dependency "@jupyterlab/apputils@~2.0.0".
warning " > @krassowski/jupyterlab-lsp@1.0.0" has incorrect peer dependency "@jupyterlab/cells@~2.0.0".
warning " > @krassowski/jupyterlab-lsp@1.0.0" has incorrect peer dependency "@jupyterlab/codeeditor@~2.0.0".
warning " > @krassowski/jupyterlab-lsp@1.0.0" has incorrect peer dependency "@jupyterlab/codemirror@~2.0.0".
warning " > @krassowski/jupyterlab-lsp@1.0.0" has incorrect peer dependency "@jupyterlab/completer@~2.0.0".
warning " > @krassowski/jupyterlab-lsp@1.0.0" has incorrect peer dependency "@jupyterlab/coreutils@~4.0.0".
warning " > @krassowski/jupyterlab-lsp@1.0.0" has incorrect peer dependency "@jupyterlab/docmanager@~2.0.0".
warning " > @krassowski/jupyterlab-lsp@1.0.0" has incorrect peer dependency "@jupyterlab/docregistry@~2.0.0".
warning " > @krassowski/jupyterlab-lsp@1.0.0" has incorrect peer dependency "@jupyterlab/fileeditor@~2.0.0".
warning " > @krassowski/jupyterlab-lsp@1.0.0" has incorrect peer dependency "@jupyterlab/notebook@~2.0.0".
warning " > @krassowski/jupyterlab-lsp@1.0.0" has incorrect peer dependency "@jupyterlab/rendermime@~2.0.0".
warning " > @krassowski/jupyterlab-lsp@1.0.0" has incorrect peer dependency "@jupyterlab/services@~5.0.0".
warning " > @krassowski/jupyterlab-lsp@1.0.0" has incorrect peer dependency "@jupyterlab/statusbar@~2.0.0".
warning " > @krassowski/jupyterlab-lsp@1.0.0" has incorrect peer dependency "@jupyterlab/tooltip@~2.0.0".
warning " > @krassowski/jupyterlab-lsp@1.0.0" has unmet peer dependency "@lumino/algorithm@*".
warning " > @krassowski/jupyterlab-lsp@1.0.0" has unmet peer dependency "@lumino/widgets@*".
warning " > @krassowski/jupyterlab-lsp@1.0.0" has unmet peer dependency "codemirror@*".
warning "@krassowski/jupyterlab-lsp > @krassowski/jupyterlab_go_to_definition@1.0.0" has incorrect peer dependency "@jupyterlab/application@~2.0.0".
warning "@krassowski/jupyterlab-lsp > @krassowski/jupyterlab_go_to_definition@1.0.0" has incorrect peer dependency "@jupyterlab/apputils@~2.0.0".
warning "@krassowski/jupyterlab-lsp > @krassowski/jupyterlab_go_to_definition@1.0.0" has incorrect peer dependency "@jupyterlab/codeeditor@~2.0.0".
warning "@krassowski/jupyterlab-lsp > @krassowski/jupyterlab_go_to_definition@1.0.0" has incorrect peer dependency "@jupyterlab/codemirror@~2.0.0".
warning "@krassowski/jupyterlab-lsp > @krassowski/jupyterlab_go_to_definition@1.0.0" has incorrect peer dependency "@jupyterlab/coreutils@~4.0.0".
warning "@krassowski/jupyterlab-lsp > @krassowski/jupyterlab_go_to_definition@1.0.0" has incorrect peer dependency "@jupyterlab/docmanager@~2.0.0".
warning "@krassowski/jupyterlab-lsp > @krassowski/jupyterlab_go_to_definition@1.0.0" has incorrect peer dependency "@jupyterlab/docregistry@~2.0.0".
warning "@krassowski/jupyterlab-lsp > @krassowski/jupyterlab_go_to_definition@1.0.0" has incorrect peer dependency "@jupyterlab/fileeditor@~2.0.0".
warning "@krassowski/jupyterlab-lsp > @krassowski/jupyterlab_go_to_definition@1.0.0" has incorrect peer dependency "@jupyterlab/notebook@~2.0.0".
warning "@krassowski/jupyterlab-lsp > @krassowski/jupyterlab_go_to_definition@1.0.0" has incorrect peer dependency "@jupyterlab/observables@~3.0.0".
warning "@krassowski/jupyterlab-lsp > @krassowski/jupyterlab_go_to_definition@1.0.0" has incorrect peer dependency "@jupyterlab/services@~5.0.0".
warning "@krassowski/jupyterlab-lsp > @krassowski/jupyterlab_go_to_definition@1.0.0" has unmet peer dependency "@lumino/algorithm@*".
warning "@krassowski/jupyterlab-lsp > @krassowski/jupyterlab_go_to_definition@1.0.0" has unmet peer dependency "codemirror@*".
[5/5] Building fresh packages...
success Saved lockfile.
Done in 5.37s.

[LabBuildApp] > node C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\staging\yarn.js yarn-deduplicate -s fewer
[LabBuildApp] yarn run v1.15.2
$ C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab\staging\node_modules\.bin\yarn-deduplicate -s fewer
Done in 0.45s.

[LabBuildApp] > node C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\staging\yarn.js run build:prod:minimize
[LabBuildApp] yarn run v1.15.2
$ ensure-max-old-space webpack --config webpack.prod.minimize.config.js
ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@jupyterlab/settingregistry' in 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab\staging\node_modules\@krassowski\jupyterlab-lsp\lib'
    at C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab\staging\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:925:10
    at C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab\staging\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js:401:22
    at C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab\staging\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js:130:21
    at C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab\staging\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js:224:22
    at C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab\staging\node_modules\neo-async\async.js:2830:7
    at C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab\staging\node_modules\neo-async\async.js:6877:13
    at C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab\staging\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js:214:25
    at C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab\staging\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:184:12
    at C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab\staging\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:238:5
    at eval (eval at create (C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab\staging\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:13:1)
    at C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab\staging\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\UnsafeCachePlugin.js:37:5
    at C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab\staging\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:238:5
    at eval (eval at create (C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab\staging\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:13:1)
    at C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab\staging\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:238:5
    at eval (eval at create (C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab\staging\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:25:1)
    at C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab\staging\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\DescriptionFilePlugin.js:42:38
    at C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab\staging\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:238:5
    at eval (eval at create (C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab\staging\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:26:1)
    at C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab\staging\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\ModuleKindPlugin.js:23:37
    at C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab\staging\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:238:5
    at eval (eval at create (C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab\staging\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:13:1)
    at C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab\staging\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:238:5
    at eval (eval at create (C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab\staging\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:13:1)
    at C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab\staging\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\forEachBail.js:30:14
    at C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab\staging\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:238:5
    at eval (eval at create (C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab\staging\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:13:1)
    at C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab\staging\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\UnsafeCachePlugin.js:37:5
    at C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab\staging\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:238:5
    at eval (eval at create (C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab\staging\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:13:1)
    at C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab\staging\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:238:5
    at eval (eval at create (C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab\staging\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:25:1)
    at C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab\staging\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\DescriptionFilePlugin.js:42:38
    at C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab\staging\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:238:5
    at eval (eval at create (C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab\staging\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:14:1)
    at C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab\staging\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:238:5
    at eval (eval at create (C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab\staging\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:25:1)
resolve '@jupyterlab/settingregistry' in 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab\staging\node_modules\@krassowski\jupyterlab-lsp\lib'
  Parsed request is a module
  using description file: C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab\staging\node_modules\@krassowski\jupyterlab-lsp\package.json (relative path: ./lib)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
    resolve as module
      C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab\staging\node_modules\@krassowski\jupyterlab-lsp\lib\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab\staging\node_modules\@krassowski\jupyterlab-lsp\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab\staging\node_modules\@krassowski\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab\staging\node_modules\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\share\jupyter\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\share\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      C:\ProgramData\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      C:\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      looking for modules in C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab\staging\node_modules
        using description file: C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab\staging\package.json (relative path: ./node_modules)
          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
          using description file: C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab\staging\package.json (relative path: ./node_modules/@jupyterlab/settingregistry)
            no extension
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab\staging\node_modules\@jupyterlab\settingregistry doesn't exist
            .wasm
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab\staging\node_modules\@jupyterlab\settingregistry.wasm doesn't exist
            .mjs
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab\staging\node_modules\@jupyterlab\settingregistry.mjs doesn't exist
            .js
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab\staging\node_modules\@jupyterlab\settingregistry.js doesn't exist
            .json
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab\staging\node_modules\@jupyterlab\settingregistry.json doesn't exist
            as directory
              C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab\staging\node_modules\@jupyterlab\settingregistry doesn't exist
child_process.js:651
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Command failed: C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab\staging\node_modules\.bin\webpack.CMD --config webpack.prod.minimize.config.js
    at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:630:11)
    at Object.execFileSync (child_process.js:648:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab\staging\node_modules\@jupyterlab\buildutils\lib\ensure-max-old-space.js:38:17)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1138:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:986:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  status: 1,
  signal: null,
  output: [ null, null, null ],
  pid: 9960,
  stdout: null,
  stderr: null
}
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.

[LabBuildApp] JupyterLab failed to build
[LabBuildApp] Traceback (most recent call last):

[LabBuildApp]   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\debuglog.py", line 47, in debug_logging
    yield

[LabBuildApp]   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\labapp.py", line 98, in start
    command=command, app_options=app_options)

[LabBuildApp]   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\commands.py", line 459, in build
    command=command, clean_staging=clean_staging)

[LabBuildApp]   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\commands.py", line 669, in build
    raise RuntimeError(msg)

[LabBuildApp] RuntimeError: JupyterLab failed to build

[LabBuildApp] Exiting application: JupyterLab
```

How can I solve this error in order to be able to use the jupyterlab-lsp extension?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: FYI for JupyterLab 3.0 the Node.js and the build step are no longer required when installing using pip/conda.